# Magento 2 order email into spam because of use system account

Tags: magento2

New order emails in my Magento 2.2.1 are going to spam, and i know why because tested it in mail-tester.com. Magento 2 uses the system account to send emails and thats not a good idea, because i am using a cloudserver.

The sender is in that case cloud.tricotstoffen.nl

I want to send from an adress i made in my email server. Can i use an other account than the system account?

Comment: Did you figure this out?  I'm having the same problem.  Even more confusing, the "Contact Us" form uses a sender configured in Magento with a "someone@mydomain.com" address whereas all transactional emails have "my-cpanel-user@some-id.myhost.com".  It's very unprofessional AND it's going to spam.  How do you fix this??

Comment: Yes, it was nog sending via SMTP. So i implemented the SMTP extension from mageside, now working fine

Comment: I can't get any of the SMTP extensions to work either.  In those cases, test emails work and the contact-us form works but transactional emails don't get sent at all through an SMTP extension.

Comment: brian, you can easaly contact mageside and they will help you. They also did it in my case, i had the port wrong